# How to add object attribute using useState (react hook) from different state that is set by children?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and I hope it is not a duplicate question here, somewhere and sorry if my explanation is wrong. So, I got this 'createEvent' panel that has 3 children's; name, start date (comes from a calendar component), end date (also) and details that come from the input text area. I created 'createEvent' panel as a parent that contains states for every data that come from the child. Inside the parent component, I want to create an object that can be sent to the backend. I tried to get data from children and using useState() to give values to the object attributes. If I try to get data using input from parent it works, but not getting input from children and I don't know what to do.
I`ll leave here examples of one child, create Event panel and post request. If I figure out how to do with these examples, I'll know to do it forward.

insert name component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './title.style.css';


export default function Title(props) {

    const [name, setName] = useState(props.name);

    function handlerName(e) {
        props.handlerName(e.target.value);
    }

    return(
        <div class="md-form active-cyan active-cyan-2 mb-3">
          <input 
            class="form-control" 
            type="text" 
            placeholder={name} 
            aria-label="Name"
            onChange={(e) => {handlerName(e)}}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

create event panel

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './createEvent.style.css';
import Name from '../input/title.component.js';
import Calendar from '../input/calendar.component.js';
import Details from '../input/details.component.js';
import CardService from '../../service/CardService.js';


export default function CreateEvent() {

    const [eventName, setEventName] = useState("");
    const [eventStartDate, setEventStartDate] = useState(new Date());
    const [eventEndDate, setEventEndDate] = useState(new Date());
    const [eventDetails, setEventDetails] = useState("");
    const [eventObject, setEventObject] = useState({
        "name": "",
        "startDate": new Date(),
        "endDate": new Date(),
        "details": ""   
    });

    async function handleName(name1){
        await setEventName(name1);
    }
    async function handleStartDate(date){
        await setEventObject({startDate: date});
    }
    async function handleEndDate(date){
        await setEventObject({endDate: date});
    }
    async function handleDetails(value){
        await setEventObject({details: value});
    }
    function handleSubmit(e) {
        CardService.postEvent(eventObject)
    }   
    return(
        <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
            <div className="Create-event">
                <div>
                    <Name name={'Insert event name'}  handlerName={handleName} />
                </div>
                <div className="date">
                    <Calendar type="submit" handlerDate={handleStartDate} date={eventStartDate}/>
                </div>
                <div className="date">
                    <Calendar type="submit" handlerDate={handleEndDate} date={eventEndDate}/>
                </div>
                <div className="text">
                    <Details type="submit" handleDetails={handleDetails}/>
                </div>
                <button className="createButton" >
                    Create   
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    );
}
```

post request

```
const CardService = {

    postEvent(value1){
        fetch("http://localhost:8080/event/ReminderApp/api/v1/event/" ,
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
               "Content-Type" : "application/JSON" ,
            },
            dataType: "json",
            body: JSON.stringify(value1),
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {console.log(json)
        })
        .catch(err => {
             console.log('Type send failed', err);
        });
    },

    getEvents() {
       return fetch('http://localhost:8080/event/ReminderApp/api/v1/event')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
            return response;
        });
    }, 
    
    deleteEvent(value) {
        fetch("http://localhost:8080/event/ReminderApp/api/v1/event/" + value,
        {
            method: 'DELETE',
        })
        .catch(err => {
             console.log('Type send failed', err);
        });
    },
};

export default CardService;
```

I tried to set all createEvent states in handle function and after using useEffect to set all fields from the object, but the app got broken. I tried to setEventObject() inside the handleSubmit function and call CardService.postEvent() but it sent the default object.

What I show you now, it is the last version of my attemps.

Comment: why `body: JSON.stringify(value1)` and not just `body: value1`?

Comment: @Apostolos I tried with JSON string to see if it works :D

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you! I changed the createEvent to class.